# Calling a cv::Mat as a uchar* from c++ to a WPF application BitmapSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, opencv

I have an opencv based dll, in c++. I need to load a cv::Mat image in the dll, and then call it from a C# UI. I had this working in WinForms, but now am moving to WPF.

I have exposed the following function in the dll:

```
__declspec(dllexport)uchar* GetBlankFrame(void)
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("D://data/TestPattern.jpg", 1);
    static cv::Mat tmp;
    cv::cvtColor(img, tmp, CV_BGRA2BGR);
    return tmp.data;

}
```

In a winForms application, I used to use this to create a Bitmap:

```
 [DllImport("tester.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetBlankFrame();


IntPtr frame = GetBlankFrame();
 Bitmap blank = new Bitmap(600, 800, 3 * 600, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, GetBlankFrame());
```

This works fine.

Now, i am attempting to move this functionality to the WPF application. To show the image, It seems that I need to use `BitmapSource` instead of `Bitmap`.

I am trying:

```
 IntPtr frame = GetBlankFrame();
                 BitmapSource srcFrame = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(frame, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
```

but it gives me:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll
```

Where am i going wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this like so:

```
   public BitmapSource convertBitmap(Bitmap source)
        {
            return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(source.GetHbitmap(), IntPtr.Zero,
     Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
        }


 IntPtr frame = GetBlankFrame();
                Bitmap blank = new Bitmap(600, 800, 3 * 600, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, frame);

                BitmapSource src = convertBitmap(blank);
```

Not sure if this is the best/most efficent way (open to more suggestions), but it looks to be working.